# Existe algum problema em usar um software multi-thread com SQLite?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sqlite

Há problemas em utilizar um software multi-thread com um banco do SQLite? Esse banco terá apenas uma conexão, porém o software que irá acessá-lo é multi-thread (servidor de aplicação). Existe algum problema? A biblioteca do SQLite é capaz de gerenciar os comandos dessa conexão?

Answer (score 1):

## Há problemas em utilizar um software multi-thread com um banco do SQLite?

Não. [Vale a pena ler este documento que explica como configurar seu banco para suportar *multithreading*](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html).

## A biblioteca do SQLite é capaz de gerenciar os comandos dessa conexão?

É. Tudo depende da linguagem que sua aplicação é feita e da biblioteca escolhida. Alguns exemplos:

- C#: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001129/multithreading-in-c-sharp-sqlite
- C: http://dev.yorhel.nl/doc/sqlaccess
- Python: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#multithreading